# jQuery target input tag with required attr

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a simple date section in my form. I have `5` `select` tags:

- 1 for the Month - id&name attr ="userdobm"
- 1 for the Year - id&name attr ="userdoby"
- 1 for (29) Days - id&name attr ="userdobd29"
- 1 for (30) Days - id&name attr ="userdobd30"
- 1 for (31) Days - id&name attr ="userdobd31"

All of the `5` `select` tags have unique ID's

By default (29)Days and (30)Days are set on `display:none` without `required` attr and (31)Days is set on `display:block` with `required` attr.

When a user selects a Month e.g. February

(30)Days and (31)Days will be set to `display:none` without `required` attr and (29)Days is set on `display:block` with `required` attr.

Code for the above:

```
$("#userdobm").change(function() {
    var userdobmval = $("#userdobm").val();
    if(userdobmval == 4 || userdobmval == 6 || userdobmval == 9 || userdobmval == 11) {
        $("#userdobd30").css('display','block').val('').prop('required', true);
        $("#userdobd29,#userdobd31").css('display','none').val('').removeAttr('required');
    } else if (userdobmval == 2) {
        $("#userdobd29").css('display','block').val('').prop('required', true);
        $("#userdobd30,#userdobd31").css('display','none').val('').removeAttr('required');
    } else {
        $("#userdobd31").css('display','block').val('').prop('required', true);
        $("#userdobd29,#userdobd30").css('display','none').val('').removeAttr('required');
    }
});
```

My problem is. How do I get the value of the current Days `select` tag that has a `required` attr?

Comment: A code sample would be helpful

Comment: provide the html dom, so we can give you the selectors...otherwise we are just writing random code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to have only one select for the day, and hide the necessary day options based on the month? Considering the way you are doing it you may also need another select for when February has 28 days.

Comment: @winterblood yeah I just decided to set feb on 29.

Comment: @abc123 I added the id&name attr of the select tags. Would that be ok to work with?

Comment: can this have a flow with it? IE user picks month then year then last day of the month is auto populated via Date JavaScript object?

Comment: I beleive you can avoid using the "required" attribute just using the `:visible` selector... BUT it is not recommended for performance. Another option would be to use a CSS class like: `.hide {display: none;}` and use it in this way: `$("select.hide").not()`, i.e. get the select tags which are not hidden.

Comment: @abc123 The flow is user picks month -> then the day changes to fit the month picked (see the jquery code above) -> user then picks the day then year. (Is that what you asked? Correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `[attribute]` will return any elements that have that attribute (regardless of whether a value is specified). So something like `$('select[required]').val();` should return the value of an dropdown like `<select required> ... </select>`. [Here's](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) the jQuery docs for the attribute selector. Let me know if you have any questions :)

#### Better option

Instead of 3 dobd selects, just have one, and change the number of options in it dynamically.. The method below also adjusts for leap years :)

```
$("#userdobm, #userdoby").change(function() {
    var max = new Date($('#userdoby').val(), $('#userdobm').val(), 0).getDate();
    $('#userdobd').empty();
    for (var i=1; i<=max; i++)
    {
        $('#userdobd').append("<option>"+i+"</option>");
    }
});
```

Comment: that would be ok but the prob is that I have about 5 different select tags in the form as a whole and they have `required` attr. Even the month and year `select` tags have `required` attr. If I use `$('select[required]').val()` I think it would target all of them? Not sure though. Would it? Because I just need to target just 1 of the (3) Days `Select` tags in this problem.

Comment: Honestly, using three different selects for the same purpose is not the best approach.. Check my updated "Better option" for an easy solution that will update the number of days on a single "userdobd" select, which allows you to select it normally it's id e.g. `$('#userdobd').val()`.. Let me know if this makes sense or if you have any questions :)

Comment: yeah I have been getting some feedback on that idea haha I'm adjusting my code to the suggestions. Talk about peer pressure lol :)) gonna try your code.

Comment: Ok just tried this. Its less code and does the job. Thanks for this!

Comment: this is slow because you are appending IE7 would be horrid...you should make a variable then fill it with you html then write to the DOM all at once.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach would be to conditionally load the number of days based on the year and month currently selected by the user, this would also remove the problem of having multiple required attributes to the select value for days (And should handle leap years).

```
$('#Month').change(function(){
    updateDays();
});

$('#Year').change(function(){
    updateDays();
});

function updateDays(){
    var year = $('#Year').val();
    var daysInMonth = daysInMonth($('#Month').val(), year);

    for(var i=0;i<=daysInMonth;i++){
        $('#Day').append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",i)
         .text(i)); 
    }

    function daysInMonth(month,year) 
    {
       return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
    }
}

updateDays();
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tMm7/3/)

Comment: +1 on simplicity and use of native JS Date() method :) one thing you might improve on is rewriting to `$('#Day').append($('<option>', { value: i, text: i }));`

Answer (score 2):

To immediately answer your question there are a few approaches you could do that ultimately hinge on determining the visibility. This is most easily done if you apply a class to each of the selects with a day. `$('select.userdobd:visible').val()` or `$('select.visible').val()` if you apply a class 'visible' instead of modifying the css directly in your month select's .change() method

Though, as has been suggested in the comments a more efficient method would be to just use *one select* and hide the options (especially if you're sending POST data to a server side script like php)

```
$("#userdobm").change(function() {
    var userdobmval = $("#userdobm").val();
    if(userdobmval == 4 || userdobmval == 6 || userdobmval == 9 || userdobmval == 11) {
        $("#userdobd").val('').find('option[value="30"]').show();
        $("#userdobd").val('').find('option[value="31"]').hide();
    } else if (userdobmval == 2) {
        $("#userdobd").val('').find('option[value="30"], option[value="31"]').hide();
    } else {
        $("#userdobd").val('').find('option[value="30"], option[value="31"]').show();
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erZVy/2/) of it in action

**EDIT: Note that this does *not* account for leap years**

***EDIT: Also note that there are still more efficient ways of doing this kind of operation. Sparko mentioned a great way using JS's native Date() constructor!***

#### **Last but not least**

jQuery has another project called ui. In the which they have a particularly useful [datepicker widget](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). I would recommend at least checking it out ;) This would not only take care of handling all of this but allows for a nice display for the user to click to a date with a familiar interface.

Comment: while, I'm running this up on a jsfiddle do you still have the three selects, or did you consolidate them into one with 31 options?

Comment: Due to popular demand I am changing the code with the single dynamic select tag.

Comment: @joespina Glad you found one of the nicer solutions fitting. For reference my code had two problems, one was #userdob instead of #userdobd and the other is it's looking for the val tag instead of value (crossing my jquery and html, it must be getting late). Updating my answer

Comment: ahhh didn't catch that when I was testing your code. It's good +1!

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/ksJ8t/4/

This does what you want.

JS:

```
$('#userdobd').prop('disabled', true);

function SetDays() {
    if ($('#userdobm').val() !== undefined && $('#userdoby').val() !== undefined) {
        $('#userdobd').prop('disabled', false);
        var d = new Date($('#userdoby').val(), $('#userdobm').val(), 0);
        console.log(d.getDate() + "Year " + d.getFullYear() + " Month " + d.getMonth());
        var options = '';
        for (var i = 1; i <= d.getDate(); i++) {
            options = options + "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
        }
        $('#userdobd').html(options);
    }
}

$("#userdobm, #userdoby").focus(function(){
  SetDays();
}).change(function() {
    SetDays();
});
```